# Is there an alternative way to create a clean PHP process than shell_exec?

Tags: php

I'm trying to convert a PHP site to static site without rewrite, so I just execute the pages with shell_exec on my computer and capture the output.

It's working, but it's pretty slow and there are 20 thousand pages or so, so generating the static site from scratch takes about an hour.

I'm doing it on Windows and AFAIK process creation is expensive on Windows, so maybe that's why it's slow.

Is there an other way to get a clean PHP process environment, so I can create the next page from a clean slate, without creating a completely new process with shell_exec? Some way to do a custom reset of the current process environment maybe? (removing included files, variables)

Comment: Your diagnostic can't be quite right. That's about 5.5 seconds / page. Windows doesn't need 5 seconds to start a process.

Comment: According to my latest measurement 6000 pages took 25 minutes which is 4 pages per second. I can improve only process creation, I think, because I can't really make php or the database go faster without rewriting the whole thing which I want to avoid if possible.

Comment: Dammit, did I just get basic maths wrong?? 20,000 pages in 3600 seconds is of course 5.5 pages per second, not the other way round. In any case, unless you run a profiler you can't really tell where the bottleneck is. You can always use a third-party grabber written in C. Also, is slowness an issue because you want to schedule the process to be done repeatedly?

Comment: Yes, several times a week. It involves importing a several hundred megabyte database but after that the site is static, so I thought I could simply host it as a generated static site instead of uploading and importing the sql dump to the server. But if generating the static site this way is so slow then it's not really practical.